# jQuery - Need to submit form once i click on calendar option

Tags: jquery

Im using the following plugin to display a calendar -[(plugin URL)](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) does anyone know if its possible to submit a form when a calendar date is clicked and have that result come through into PHP so i can use $_POST to get what i clicked?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if the plugin sends you events. You can handle "dateSelected", it seems, and in that handler you can submit your form.

```
$('input.whatever').datePicker().bind("dateSelected", function(ev, date, td, selected) {
   if (selected) {
     $('#your_form').submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: The plugin passes you the selected date as the second argument to the function (at least, that's what the documentation says).  I have to assume that it also drops the date value into your form field (the `<input>` that you set up with the date picker), so if you submit the form then it'll probably just be there automagically.